# Thousands of extraneous gunicorn workers

Tags: django, ubuntu, gunicorn

I'm using gunicorn 19.7.1 appserver with nginx reverse proxy for a Django project (Ubuntu 14.04 machine).

`ps aux | grep gunicorn | grep -v grep | wc -l` yields **3043** at the moment.

Whereas in `/etc/init/gunicorn.conf`, I've always had `-w 33`. Yet these extra workers persist even if I do `sudo service gunicorn stop` and `sudo service gunicorn start`.

How do I kill the extraneous workers?

---

**How did this happen?**

The worker count of `33` has always been properly configured on my busy production system.

However a few hours ago, I was trying python's `multiprocessing` on the server and things went south. Gunicorn workers ate up all the memory and took out the resident redis instances as well.

[image]

I reverted the change and have managed to get everything back online, except the memory hasn't been released and I've had to cope with these legacy gunicorn workers. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yet these extra workers persist even if I do `sudo service gunicorn stop` and `sudo service gunicorn start`.

`service` only manages `service`-initiated processes, so if you started Gunicorn workers outside of the service framework, these workers will continue to live even if you `stop`.

> How do I kill the extraneous workers?

**The fast way:**

Run this command to list all `gunicorn` process IDs and terminate them, and then restart Gunicorn:

```bash
$ pkill gunicorn
$ sudo service gunicorn start
```

**The better way:**

1. Identify your "desired" Gunicorn workers by finding the parent:

   ```
   $ sudo service gunicorn status
   ```

   Note the parent process ID. Let's say it's `123`.
2. Save a list of all the "desired" workers' PIDs:

   ```
    $ echo 123 > desired_workers
    $ pgrep -P 123 >> desired_workers
   ```
3. Save a list of all workers' PIDs:

   ```
    $ pgrep gunicorn > all_workers
   ```
4. Terminate the "undesired" workers:

   ```
    $ cat desired_workers all_workers | sort | uniq -u | xargs kill
   ```

Comment: So I opted for the better method - it looked more surgical to me. I successfully created the desired files in `/tmp`. In the end, when I ran `cat desired_workers all_workers | sort | uniq -u | xargs kill`, nothing happened. Specifically, `ps aux | grep gunicorn | grep -v grep | wc -l` still gives me **3043**, nor has memory been released. Any ideas?

Comment: @HassanBaig Are you the owner of the processes? If not, you may need to `sudo kill` instead of `kill`.

Comment: Yea I actually tried this thing both as `root` and via `cat desired_workers all_workers | sort | uniq -u | xargs sudo kill`. Neither way killed those processes; I still see **3043**. Maybe a different approach ought to be applied here?

Comment: `pkill gunicorn` and `sudo pkill gunicorn` didn't work either. Still 3043 gunicorn workers. Any leads?

Comment: @HassanBaig I don't know why you'd be unable to terminate a process. They retain the same process IDs? (If not, perhaps some other process is recreating them?) Try `$ kill -9`?

Comment: I tried `-INT` first (as `root`), and it worked. I.e. `cat desired_workers all_workers | sort | uniq -u | xargs kill -INT`. I think if you want, you could add that and the `KILL` variants to your already great reply as well. Would be good for future readers.